# Prestashop 1.7 - filtering not working, showing empty results

Tags: filtering, prestashop, blocklayered

I have got a problem on my store (still under development) - http://condesign.pl/officina . It's all about filtering products, for example here: http://condesign.pl/officina/pl/521-akcesoria-ze-skory . All the attributes on the left are being displayed correctly, with numbers of products in brackets, but when You click on any filter (like size or color), the list of results is empty.

Help please!

Comment: Stack is not good place to ask this kind of questions. If You need any help Join Prestashop group on Facebook. If You have any questions or need support just ask here https://www.facebook.com/prestashark.eu/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Try yo do the exact same thing with the default theme of Prestahsop. Because this looks like a theme issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is very large bug in ps_facetedsearch module... You can't do anything with this. You must wait for fix. https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/9684 here is list of bugs in module.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake - this module uses table ps_stock_available. I was migrating data from previous store to this one (only in phpmyadmin, not panel, because of very different structures), and I didn't know about this table. So it was about my missing data.